# If Range contains Cell with Value > 8 then MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am programming a time recording sheet. If for one weekday a value > 8 (so more than 8 hours) is filled in. I want a Messagebox to pop up.

i am struggling with the code I am currently using.

Also it would be great if the Macro would run automatically when the cells are being filled in.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem are very much appreciated.

```
Sub GenehmigungMehrarbeit()

   If Range("F14,F26").Value > 8 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit mit dem Teamlead abgesprochen?")

   If Range("G14,G26").Value > 8 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit abgesprochen?")

    ElseIf Range("H14,H26").Value > 8 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit abgesprochen?")

    ElseIf Range("I14,I26").Value > 8 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit  abgesprochen?")

    ElseIf Range("J14,J26").Value > 8 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit abgesprochen?")

  End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume that column F to J are for Monday to Friday. Also do you want to display the message box as soon as 8+ are entered?

Comment: What you want is a worksheet change event. This will give a `Target` as `Range`. You can both check if that `Target` is within a certain range/column AND if it's value is larger than 8.

Comment: Excactly F to J are the columns for Monday through Friday.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try the worksheet change event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write following code at Worksheet level (right click on Sheetname, View code and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("F14:J26")) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value > 8 Then
                MsgBox "You entered 8+ hours!!"
                Target.Value = ""
                Target.Select
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use this simple and short code for the range F14 to J26. You can change the rage in code as per your requirement in line  "If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("F14:J26")) Is Nothing Then"

Comment: I'm sorry to ask again, but the code you showed here deletes the value > 8 after the MsgBox popped up. Is there a way that only makes the MsgBox show up but then lets me continue putting data in the other cells?

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn you can delete or comment out the line Target.Value = "" in my code.

Answer (score 3):

## Overtime Worksheet Change Event

### The Code

**Module 1** (or any you're using)

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenehmigungMehrarbeit(Worksheet As Worksheet)  ' Overtime

    ' List of Check Range Addresses
    Const cRanges As String = "F14:F26,G14:G26,H14:H26,I14:I26,J14:J26"
    ' German List of Days
    Const cDays As String = "Montag,Dienstag,Mittwoch,Donnerstag,Freitag"
    ' Message 1
    Const strMsg1 = "Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit für den "
    ' Message 2
    Const strMsg2 = " mit dem Teamlead abgesprochen?"
    Const cHours As Long = 8  ' Hours

    Dim vntR As Variant   ' Check Range Array
    Dim vntD As Variant   ' Days Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Ranges/Days Array Elements Counter

    ' Split List of Range Addresses to Check Range Array
    vntR = Split(cRanges, ",")
    ' Split German List of Days to Days Array
    vntD = Split(cDays, ",")

    ' In This workbook's Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheet.Name)
        ' Loop through elements of Check Range Array (Days Array).
        For i = 0 To UBound(vntR)
            ' Check if sum of the current Check Range is greater than cHours.
            If WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(Trim(vntR(i))).Value) _
                    > cHours Then
                ' Build the (daily) message.
                MsgBox strMsg1 & Trim(vntD(i)) & strMsg2, vbInformation, vntD(i)
                Exit For ' Stop checking.
                ' Note: The message box will pop up only for the first found
                '       range with the sum greater than Hours (cHours).
                '       If you want the messages to pop up for every range
                '       with the sum greater than Hours, you should out
                '       comment the previous line.
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

**Sheet1** (or any you're using)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("F14:J26")) Is Nothing Then _
            GenehmigungMehrarbeit Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: The Code runs perfectly

Comment: @Anna von Blohn: I've noticed you haven't [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)ed (0 reputation needed) or [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)d (15 reputation needed) any of your answers received. You might wanna do so, if you got acceptable answers. It's the check mark for accept, and the upper arrow for upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I did so now

Comment: One last thing. How can I change that once I have clicked away the MsgBox it won't appear again for the same cell?

Comment: @Anna von Blohn: Using my code e.g. you would have to implement another array and declare it as **Static** and in the **For Next** loop before the **If** statement, use another **If** statement to check if the array contains the current **i** and before **Exit For** you would have to add a line which adds the current **i** to the array.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

Follow the instructions on the image:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, rng5 As Range

        Set rng1 = Range("F14,F26")
        Set rng2 = Range("G14,G26")
        Set rng3 = Range("H14,H26")
        Set rng4 = Range("I14,I26")
        Set rng5 = Range("J14,J26")

        If Not Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, rng2) Is Nothing _
            Or Not Intersect(Target, rng3) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, rng4) Is Nothing _
            Or Not Intersect(Target, rng5) Is Nothing Then _

            If Target.Value > 8 Then
                If Not Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit mit dem Teamlead abgesprochen?")
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit abgesprochen?")
                End If
            End If

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately the code doesn't do anything. Do you know how to "tell VBA to start the macro when values in the cells are changed"?

Comment: That delivers the bug "Run time error 1004: The method "Range" für the object '_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the answer below worked and the problem is solved!

Comment: One last thing. If the the Messagebox is clicked away once. How can I stop it from appearing a second time for the same checked cell?

Comment: i can 't  think for any possible solution for this.

Comment: @Error1004, `Exit sub` ;)

Comment: i not sure if this solution works because the event will trigger again if any change take place in the range.

Answer (score 2):

`Range("F14,F26").Value` returns the value only of `F14`, completely ignoring the `F26`.

This is how to build the event with a msgbox for 1 cell:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("F14")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Range("F14") > 8 Then
        MsgBox "Something in German"
    End If

End Sub
```

Put the above code in the corresponding worksheet, not in a module:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your edit! Unfortunately non of the suggestions work. Do you have an idea on how to start the macro when changing the values in those cells?

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn - copy and paste the code in the Worksheet, not in the module.

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn - see the edit, with a red arrow, pointing where to put the code.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you know how to use this code for a larger range of cells instead of Range("F14:J26")? I'm guessing repeating the code 60 times would be really inefficient... Sorry btw. I have just recently started using VBA

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn - You are welcome. For the 60 times, the easiest way is to unite the cells in one range and check the cells with a `for each cell in unitedRange` - loop. Concerning the inefficiency of the 60 ifs - it would be still extremely fast if you do it this way, the only problem is that it would be a bit difficult to maintain, if there is a need - the changes should be made in 60 places. And some senior VBA developer may frown upon it. But as far as VBA Devs do not exist, do not worry about the frown :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AnnavonBlohn - welcome - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use Worksheet_Change event in VBA to run the code automatically when something is changed in the sheet. Copy the following code into the sheet in Visual Basic Editor.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row >= 14 And Target.Row <= 26 And Target.Value > 8 Then
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit mit dem Teamlead abgesprochen?")
    ElseIf Target.Column >= 7 And Target.Column <= 11 Then
        MsgBox ("Wurde der Mehraufwand der Arbeitszeit abgesprochen?")
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

This code runs whenever you change something in the sheet. Code checks if the changed cells are between 14th and 26th rows, if the value of changed cell is greater than 8, if the cells are between specified columns etc.